# How to extend a list of elements and draw them

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I detected some communities in a network and I would like to make the process as more automated as possible, especially when a big number of communities is detected. The code I used is

```
from networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max 
import greedy_modularity_communities

c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(G))
```

That detects 3 communities.
To see the clusters and plot them, I usually run the following:

```
community_0 = sorted(c[0])
community_1 = sorted(c[1])
community_2 = sorted(c[2])
```

And to draw each set of nodes:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,circ_pos, nodelist=community_0, node_color='g', alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,circ_pos, nodelist=community_1, node_color='r', alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,circ_pos, nodelist=community_2, node_color='b', alpha=0.5)
```

where `G` is `G = nx.karate_club_graph()`.
My question is how to extend the list of `community_x`, i.e.,the x communities that can be detected using `greedy_modularity_communities`, and draw them, adding iteratively the parameter in the nodelist.

Comment: For me, the only limitation is regarding the `node_color`argument you would need a pre-defined list of colors to iterate over an uncertain number of nodes. With that solved you could easily add a `for` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
from networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max 
import greedy_modularity_communities

# list of detected communities 
c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(G))
sortedCommunities = []

# iterate through list of discovered communities. Sort each community and add them to new list.

for community in c:
    sortedCommunities.append(sorted(community))

# draw community
# here we are using a different color at each iteration but cycling back to the first color.

colors = ['g', 'r', 'b']
temp_counter = 0
for community in sortedCommunities:
    
    chosenColor = colors[temp_counter%3]
    temp_counter += 1
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,circ_pos, nodelist=community , node_color=chosenColor , alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Hi ExtrovetedProgrammer, thanks for your answer. Could you tell me what temp is?

Comment: temp_counter is a variable used to shuffle through the colors. You have 3 colors and to shuffle through the colors you need to go like this: 0 => 1 => 2 => 0 => 1 .... etc
So it is used as the index to select the next color in the selection cycle.

Comment: Thanks ExtrovetedProgrammer. I have asked because I get an error on temp%3 as temp has not been defined

Comment: if you are runnning my code make sure to use the correct variable name. the varaible name is temp_counter and not temp. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: I was referring to this step: `chosenColor = colors[temp%3]`. Should it be temp_counter?

Comment: actually yes my bad, it should be temp_counter. I'll reflect the correction in the original answer

Answer (score 1):

Use python `eval()` function and make a search in meta programming concept.

I provide some sample code for you:

```py
for i in range(1,3):
    eval('community_'+str(i)+' = sorted(c['+str(i)+']))'
```

Comment: Seems second line should be `eval('community_'+str(i)+' = sorted(c['+str(i)+'])')`? Or more easily written as `eval(f'community_{i} = sorted(c[{i}])')`? However, the equal sign is causing an issue.